# How to display dataset result as left to right?

Tags: dataset, report, birt

I am new to BIRT, i am trying to display my BIRT report data from left to right horizontally, Default, table data fills vertically,But i would like to have exactly opposite to it,What i have to do to achieve this?

My Dataset

```
student_name
student_1
student_2
student_3
```

My expected result would be ,

```
student_name student_1 student_2 student_3
```

How can i show data horizontally in BIRT?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you clarify the question to indicate if you there will be other data points, or if you are just creating a long string with all the names it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a *List element* bound to the dataset, instead of a table element. As shown in the screen below, the key-point is to add a grid in "detail" section of the list and set its display property to "inline". Then you can arrange one or multiple data fields as you like within this grid, embed sub-grids etc.

[image]

For example [this dummy report](http://www.visioneo.org/week-parameters) displays days of a date range from left to right. The PDF export of [this sample](http://www.visioneo.org/geographical-tree) also works using an inline list. Notice this "inline" value is not taken into account by all emitters, but it renders as expected at least with HTML and PDF emitters.